# facebook and twitter iframes requesting access set 'document.domain' error

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter

I'm putting Tweet and Facebook Like buttons on the project im working. Everything seems to be working but when click the btns I get this JS error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1357735024.html#_=1357834238249&count=none&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandals.com%2Fmain%2Fnegril%2Fne-home.cfm&size=m&text=Negril%2C%20Jamaica%20All%20Inclusive%20Vacation%20-%20Sandals%20Negril%20Beach%20Resort%20%26%20Spa&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandals.com%2Fmain%2Fnegril%2Fne-home.cfm&via=SandalsResorts from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&app_id=150389325070106&href=www.sandals.com/main/negril/ne-home.cfm&send=false&layout=button_count&width=60&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21. The frame requesting access set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', the frame being accessed set it to 'twitter.com'. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.
```

this is the code im using for fb and twitter

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
appId      : '150389325070106', // App ID from the App Dashboard
channelUrl : '//www.sandals.com', // Channel File for x-domain communication
status     : false, // check the login status upon init?
cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
frictionlessRequests: true
});
// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
};

// Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
(function(d, debug){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));


// Twitter Btn JS
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

i followed the steps in fb dev site but still get those errors :S

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, have you solved this?

Comment: Check out this post with same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433461/facebook-like-and-twitter-tweet-buttons-causing-cross-domain-issues

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the linked answer, this is an issue with Twitter's API. Alternatively to the answer on the linked question, I created a custom tweet button that looks exactly like the one of Twitter's JS API but doesn't use it and still includes the share count. Feel free to use it.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/eyecatchup/Th6P2/2/show/
Code: https://github.com/eyecatchup/tweetbutton

Comment: the problem arises when i have FB and twitter buttons, not sure with others. i modified your code a bit to show u.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Th6P2/3/show/

Comment: So what's the problem? There is no problem with my solution. When you [share the URL of your modified fiddle via twitter](https://twitter.com/bext0n/status/329276200935636992), the twitter counter increases. Check your link again - you will see 1 twitter share now.